# Build a bat file for a sequence of operations

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell, batch-file

I want to build a `*.bat` file which does the following:

- Start a `cmd` in a specific directory, input a string inside that console and hit Enter.
- Start another `cmd` in a specific directory, input another string and hit Enter
- Start `PowerShell` , input a string, hit enter, wait for that command to end, input another string, hit enter, let it compile.

Not sure if the term `input` is what I mean, but I am referring to the `>>` option when writing to a text file, if this is of any help.

Is this possible with a simple `*.bat` file and if not, how am I able to achieve this?

I have read multiple threads about using a `*.vbs` file but didn't got the hang of it.

So far I am running the simplest executions like:

```
@echo off

cd "dir1"
start cmd.exe

cd "dir2"
start cmd.exe

cd "dir3"
start Powershell ..
```

Comment: Look at my answer here for how to do the PowerShell part of your task, just be sure to `CD /D` and then run the PS accordingly (i.e. `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command`) and then run just as shown in that example. Maybe a partial starting point for you at least to get started. https://superuser.com/questions/1107084/understanding-executing-powershell-inside-batch-with-parameters/1212647#1212647

Comment: What is the purpose of starting the whole new process, rather than prompting withing the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem, and that is the usage of the `/k` directive along with some timeouts.

> To run a command in a newly opened window, you need to use `/k`

For example:

```
@echo off

start cmd.exe /k ng serve --port 4203 --host host.dev

timeout 65

cd styles\

start cmd.exe /k gulp

timeout 4

start PowerShell.exe
```

Everything after `/k` is being typed in the window and then ran.