# Powershelll argument equivalents to cmd args

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

If I'm running a file, example.exe, that takes arguments in cmd:

```
example.exe /argA=true /argB="string" /argC=confirm
```

can I do the same in powershell with

```
example.exe -argA true -argB "string" -argC confirm
```

If you can translate cmd patterns to powershell patterns, is there any guide to how cmd syntax translates into powershell syntax?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. It depends on how `example.exe` is coded in order to parse it's command line arguments.

Comment: See if this helps you any for what you are asking: https://superuser.com/questions/1107084/understanding-executing-powershell-inside-batch-with-parameters/1212647#1212647