# Day of week schedule

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, script, sync, scheduled-tasks

What can I do, if I want to schedule a task on ,for example, fifth day in month, but not during the weekend. Example: if fifth day is saturday, so task will be scheduled on monday.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: If you do not want to schedule the task on saturday, because the pc is offline, just check: run as soon as possible if a schedule was missed.

Comment: Actually, this task will be working on server so I thing your solution may not works because the server is always online.

Comment: check if the day is on weekend and schedule a one-time event next Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution I've used in the past for a similar task that I modified a little to potentially help with your need. The trick is to have the **Task Scheduler** execute a batch script and have the batch script that's executed have the logic in it to do the conditional checks to run or not.

You can use [`CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) or [`START`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to execute executable files (an app), another batch script, [execute PowerShell scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/1107084/understanding-executing-powershell-inside-batch-with-parameters/1212647#1212647), and other types of scripts. Sometimes the **Task Scheduler** scheduling isn't robust enough for special scheduling needs as in this case.

> **Essentially this solution will. . .**
>
> - Trigger it to run  **every month** on the `5th`, `6th`, and `7th` so if *Saturday* is the `5th`, *Sunday* is the `6th`, then *Monday*
>     will be the `7th` but even if Sunday is the `5th` or `6th` it'll still
>     run on *Monday* the `6th` or `7th`
>
>   [image]
> - Incorporate a batch script that will run some initial conditional logic that will check for the day of the week and take action based on
>     these conditions  whether or not to create a file with the word `Run`
>     in it, but if it already has been created with `Run` for that month
>     then `EXIT`

### Batch Script

**Note:** *The only thing you really need to adjust with this is to use the correct path in the `SET RunFile=C:\SomeFolder\SomePath\` portion to make it the correct folder or UNC path to create the run file, etc.  Then just make the `<Rest of logic needed    >` just execute or run whatever logic or script the **Task Scheduler** is running now.*

```
@ECHO ON

::: -- Set date variables for conditional logic for the current date and day of week
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=." %%A IN ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| FIND "."') DO SET rundt=%%~A
SET rundt=%rundt:~0,6%
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=." %%A IN ('WMIC PATH Win32_LocalTime GET DayOfWeek ^| FINDSTR /R [0-9]') DO SET DOW=%%~A

::: -- If the day today is 6 for Saturday or 7 for Sunday then EXIT
IF %DOW%==6 EXIT
IF %DOW%==7 EXIT

::: -- Set the run file location to create a file with "run" in it if the day is correct
SET RunFile=C:\SomeFolder\SomePath\%rundt%.run

::: -- If "Run" already found in "~\<YYYYMM>.run" file then do not run because it already has this month
FINDSTR /I Run "%RunFile%"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO :Run) ELSE (EXIT)

:Run
ECHO Run>"%RunFile%"
<Rest of logic needed    >
<CALL C:\folder\app.exe  >

EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
- [For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [Exit](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)
- [Errorlevel](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)